# How to enable all addons on startup?

Tags: python

How can blender be started with all add-ons enabled?

This is useful when testing if all addons can be loaded without any errors.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done using [`--python-expr`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options).

```shell
blender \
    --factory-startup \
    --python-expr \
    "[__import__('bpy').ops.preferences.addon_enable(module=m.__name__) for m in __import__('addon_utils').modules()]"
```

Some add-ons can be ignored, in this example `{'cycles', 'render_freestyle_svg'}`.

```shell
blender \
    --factory-startup \
    --python-expr \
    "[__import__('bpy').ops.preferences.addon_enable(module=m.__name__) for m in __import__('addon_utils').modules() if m.__name__ not in {'cycles', 'render_freestyle_svg'}]"
```